# Java Multithreading on mergesort

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a merge-sort algorithm that splits an unsorted array into multiple buckets as specified in the main method. I am required to have multiple threads where each thread does work on a single bucket to sort the numbers in that bucket and then merge the results together. How do i go about it given the following piece of code. i have done so...managed to create threads proportional to the number of array buckets...but now how do i assign the buckets to each thread worker...i have edited the code in the posting please.

```
public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numsToSort = {1,5,3,7,10,4,6,11,2,8,9,12,16,14,17,13,19,20};
    int[] sorted = bucketSort(numsToSort,3);

    System.out.print("Sorted: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(sorted[i] + " ");
    }

}

public static int[] bucketSort(int[] numbers, int bucketCount) {

    if (numbers.length <= 1)
        return numbers;
    int maxVal = numbers[0];
    int minVal = numbers[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > maxVal)
            maxVal = numbers[i];
        if (numbers[i] < minVal)
            minVal = numbers[i];
    }

    double interval = ((double) (maxVal - minVal + 1)) / bucketCount; // range of bucket
    ArrayList<Integer> buckets[] = new ArrayList[bucketCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < bucketCount; i++) // initialize buckets (initially empty)
        buckets[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) // distribute numbers to buckets
        buckets[(int) ((numbers[i] - minVal) / interval)].add(numbers[i]);

    int k = 0;
    //=======================================
    for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        //System.out.println("buckets " + i + " " + buckets[i]);

        //submitting tasks
        //for (int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
            executor.submit(new App(i));
            Collections.sort(buckets[i]); // calls Java's built-in merge sort(as a kind of “helper” sort)

            for (int j = 0; j < buckets[i].size(); j++) { // update array with the bucket content
                numbers[k] = buckets[i].get(j);
                k++;
            }

        //}
        executor.shutdown();

        System.out.println("All tasks submitted...");

        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("All tasks completed...");
    }


    return numbers;
}
```

}

class App  implements Runnable{

```
private int id;

public App(int id){
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println("starting..." + id);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("completed..." + id);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you let us know what you tried doing and got stuck with? Otherwise we'll be essentially doing the homework for you.

Comment: class App  implements Runnable{
 
 private int id;
 
 public App(int id){
  this.id = id;
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
 
  System.out.println("starting..." + id);
  
  try {
   Thread.sleep(5000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  System.out.println("completed..." + id);
 }
 
}

Comment: ^ this is not useful. Please edit your question and format your code.

Comment: i have done so...managed to create threads proportional to the number of array buckets...but now how do i assign the buckets to each thread worker...i have edited the code in the posting please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an SSCCE, while the approach is a bit different than yours (Java 8) it accomplishes what I believe you question described.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ThreadSorter
{
  private static Random random = new Random();

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<Integer> numsToSort = random.ints(0, 50).limit(60L).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    ThreadSorter testClass = new ThreadSorter();
    List<Integer> sorted = testClass.bucketSort(numsToSort, 4);

    System.out.print("Sorted: ");
    sorted.stream().forEach(i -> System.out.print(i + " "));
  }

  public List<Integer> bucketSort(List<Integer> numbers, int bucketCount)
  {

    if (numbers.size() <= 1)
      return numbers;

    Queue<ArrayList<Integer>> buckets = new LinkedList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    // create buckets
    buckets.addAll(IntStream.range(0, bucketCount)
        .mapToObj(i -> new ArrayList<Integer>()).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    // iterate numbers adding to current bucket (revolving queue additions)
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
      ArrayList<Integer> currentBucket = buckets.poll();
      currentBucket.add(numbers.get(i));
      buckets.offer(currentBucket);
    }

    // LinkedList is a queue and a list :)
    List<ArrayList<Integer>> bucketList = (List<ArrayList<Integer>>) buckets;

    for (int i = 0; i < bucketList.size(); i++)
    {
      System.out.println("buckets " + i + ":  " + bucketList.get(i));
    }

    // create Threads for each bucket
    List<Thread> threads = bucketList.stream()
        .map(e -> new Thread(new BucketSorter(e))).collect(Collectors.toList());

    // start threads
    threads.stream().forEach(Thread::start);

    // join threads (make sure all are complete before continuing)
    for (Thread t : threads)
    {
      try
      {
        t.join();
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e1)
      {}
    }

    // debug statement shoing individual buckets are sorted
    for (int i = 0; i < bucketList.size(); i++)
    {
      System.out.println("sorted buckets " + i + ":  " + bucketList.get(i));
    }

    // recombine the individual buckets and sort them
    List<Integer> newlist = (bucketList.stream().flatMap(e -> e.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    Collections.sort(newlist);

    return newlist;
  }
}
```

```
/**
   * Debug statements show the start order of the threads is not necessarily the
   * finish order.
   *
   */
  public class BucketSorter
      implements Runnable
  {
    List<Integer> bucket;

    public BucketSorter(List<Integer> bucket)
    {
      this.bucket = bucket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      System.out.println(
          "Thread Launched: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ".");
      try
      {
        Thread.sleep(random.longs(400, 2000).findFirst().orElse(200L));
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e)
      {}
      System.out.println(
          "Thread Done Sleeping: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ".");
      Collections.sort(bucket);
      System.out.println(
          "Thread Finished: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ".");
    }
  }
```